# run a method every N time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to print a sentence every 5 second and i need to pass an argument to it.

I am using `threading`

```
import threading

def printit(whatever):
  threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
  print(whatever)

var= "start"
printit(var)
```

which gives me this error

> ````bsh
> C:\Users\Wei Xi\Desktop>python test.py
> start
> Exception in thread Thread-1:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Wei Xi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
>     self.run()
>   File "C:\Users\Wei Xi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 1254, in run
>     self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
> TypeError: printit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'whatever'```
> ````

Comment: Is it intentional to have the same name for the *outer* function and the callable passed to to `threading.Timer()`?

Answer (score 3):

[threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer) constructor accepts `args` and keyword arguments `kwargs` for respective target function (`class threading.Timer(interval, function, args=None, kwargs=None)`):

```
import threading

def printit(whatever):
  threading.Timer(5.0, printit, args=(whatever,)).start()
  print(whatever)

var= "start"
printit(var)
```

Sample output will be (in "infinite" printing):

```
start
start
start
start
...
```

Comment: Which is a close friend of a fork bomb.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the possible solution:

```
import threading

def printit(whatever): 
    print(whatever)
    threading.Timer(5.0, printit, {whatever}).start() 

var = "start" 
printit(var)
```

You're getting the error because you didn't passed in `whatever` (the function parameter) when you recursively call your `printit` function.

EDIT:

However, this solution will spawn an infinite amount of threads. If you wanted to run the process as a background task, you could just use one thread by doing this.

**Note**: I uses 2 argument for this example.

```
import time
import threading


def printit(whatever, whatever2, seconds=5):
    while True:
        print(whatever)
        print(whatever2)
        time.sleep(seconds)

var = "start"
var2 = "end"

threading.Thread(target=printit, kwargs={"whatever":var, "whatever2":var2, "seconds":5}).start() 

print("Do something else")
```

Output:

```
start
end
Do something else
start
end
start
end
... (repeat start end every 5 seconds)
```

Comment: cool bro, what if i want to pass several arguments? def printit(args1,args2,args3),should i do threading.Timer(5.0, printit, {args1,args2,args3}).start() ?

Comment: Yes, but do note that this way of doing things, you're essentially spawning threads infinitely, which can be resource intensive. The other solution that uses a for loop with `time.sleep` might be a better solution if spawning threads is not what you intended to do.

Comment: I believe the reason you use thread is because you wanted to perform the `printit` function every 5 seconds, running at the background and not spawning infinite threads. If that is the case, there's a better solution than this. I will update my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `time.sleep()` function inside a while loop:

```
import time

def printit(whatever, seconds=5):
    while True:
        print(whatever)
        time.sleep(seconds)

var= "start"
printit(var) # prints "start" every 5 seconds
#start

#start

#start
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use time:

```
def printit(str_):
   time.sleep(5)
   print(str_)

var = "start"
while True:
     printit(var)
```

Comment: `TypeError: must be str, not NoneType`